# Can I take an input using InputStreamReader in static block?

Tags: java

[Code has been written. Can I use this code to take user input?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLwM6.png)

Comment: Just google it, there are many examples.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: please do not post a screenshot when a copy/paste is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Answer - technically, yes you can.

However, your example is reading a number and throwing it away.  The local variable in the `static` block goes away at the end of the block.

In general, it is a bad idea to read user input that way because:

- Handling exceptions thrown in a `static` block is not possible.  In your example, if the `Scanner` fails to read an integer an unchecked exception will be thrown.  That will crash your application with an `ExceptionInInitializerError` ...
- In some circumstances, it can be difficult to tell when (or even if) a `static` block will be run
- This is a gratuitously odd way to write this code.  Code like this is a problem for people who have to maintain it.

Normal practice is to read input in code called (directly or indirectly) from the `main(String[])` method.  That way you can control when it is read, and catch any exceptions using a handler on the "main" thread.